# Add to an asset field from a queue job

Tags: modules, queue

I'm following this to generate social share images from entries: https://ghijk.co.uk/blog/generate-dynamic-social-share-images-in-craft-cms

It's working well. But I'd like to add the generated image to an asset field on the entry, for better visibility. Is it possible to do that from a queue job?

Here's what I have so far:

```
Event::on(Entry::class, Entry::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE, function (ModelEvent $event) {
  if (!ElementHelper::isDraft($event->sender) && !ElementHelper::isRevision($event->sender)) {
    $element = $event->sender;
    Craft::$app->queue->push(new GenerateSocialCard([
      'element' => $element,
      'type' => $element->type->handle,
    ]));
  }
});
```

```
class GenerateSocialCard extends BaseJob
{
  public $element;
  public $type;
  public function execute($queue): void
  {
    $image = Browsershot::url(getenv('PRIMARY_SITE_URL') . '/social-images/' . $this->type . '/' . $this->element->id)
      ->windowSize(1200, 675)
      ->waitUntilNetworkIdle()
      ->save(getcwd() . '/social-images/' . $this->type . '/' . $this->elementId . '.png');
    
  $asset = new Asset();
  $asset->newFolderId = 1;
  $asset->filename = 'test';
  $asset->volumeId = 1;
  $asset->tempFilePath = $image;
  $asset->setScenario(Asset::SCENARIO_CREATE);

  $element->setFieldValue('seoImage', $asset);
  Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($element);

  }

  protected function defaultDescription(): ?string
  {
    return Craft::t('app', 'Generating Social Image');
  }
}
```

With this I get a `Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed` error so I'm not sure if I should be trying to update the field as part of the queue job or somewhere else.

Also not sure the asset creation part is right, but I can get to that next.

Appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 1):

The return of `Browsershot::url()` is not the asset path, so you cannot put it like this:

```
$asset->tempFilePath = $image;
```

You can just pass the path where you put on save arguments directly :

```
getcwd() . '/social-images/' . $this->type . '/' . $this->elementId . '.png'
```

but probably it will cause that file will be deleted, so the better way is to copy your file to craft temp path

```
$craftTemp  = Craft::$app->path->getTempAssetUploadsPath(true);
$path       = $craftTemp .'/' . '/sc-' . $this->elementId;
copy('getcwd() . '/social-images/' . $this->type . '/' . $this->elementId . '.png', $path);
```

then you can put it on temp path :

```
$asset->tempFilePath = $path;
```

Another thing is even this work, to save the asset field you need to save the asset first and push the element id as array in setFieldValue().

```
class GenerateSocialCard extends BaseJob
{
  public $element;
  public $type;
  public function execute($queue): void
  {
    $filePath = getcwd() . '/social-images/' . $this->type . '/' . $this->elementId . '.png';
    $image = Browsershot::url(getenv('PRIMARY_SITE_URL') . '/social-images/' . $this->type . '/' . $this->element->id)
      ->windowSize(1200, 675)
      ->waitUntilNetworkIdle()
      ->save(filePath);
    
  $craftTemp  = Craft::$app->path->getTempAssetUploadsPath(true);
  $path       = $craftTemp .'/' . '/sc-' . $this->elementId . 'png';
  copy(filePath, $path)
  $asset = new Asset();
  $asset->newFolderId = 1;
  $asset->filename = $this->elementId . '.png';
  $asset->volumeId = 1;
  $asset->tempFilePath = $path;
  $asset->setScenario(Asset::SCENARIO_CREATE);
  Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($asset);
  $element->setFieldValue('seoImage', [$asset->id]);
  Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($element);

  }

  protected function defaultDescription(): ?string
  {
    return Craft::t('app', 'Generating Social Image');
  }
}
```

PS: I didn't test the code.